# Converting (Year and Month) to (Year) in R dataframe

Tags: r, date

I have a csv file which i loaded into R. One of the column called "remaining_lease" contains data of year and month, such as "56 years 04 months". i would like to convert it into year and save it into a new column. how do I do that? thank you

Comment: That looks like a difference in years and months. It would be great, if you could add some code with `dput()` or make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try `sub("(\\d{,2}).*", "\\1", "56 years 04 months")`. Or, if `df1` is your data set, `sub("(\\d{,2}).*", "\\1", df1$remaining_lease)`. This will return a character vector that you can coerce to integer with `as.integer`.

Comment: A tidyverse solution is `stringr::str_extract(df1$remaining_lease, "\\d{1,2}")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)
# fake data
data.frame(remaining_lease = c("56 years 04 months", "20 years")) %>%

# split into columns, convert to numbers, add as months, extract year
separate(remaining_lease, c("years", "months"), sep = "years") %>%
mutate(across(years:months, ~coalesce(parse_number(.), 0)),
       date = Sys.Date() %m+% months(months + 12*years),
       year = year(date))
```

Result

```
  years months       date year
1    56      4 2079-05-10 2079
2    20      0 2043-01-10 2043
```